# Given a dataset of students' exam scores across 5 years, how can I determine what consists of a significant change in score?

Tags: t-test, pre-post-comparison

Suppose I have the data below, of student's scores changes between 2013-2016 in :

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-------+
| Student | Score Change | Absolute Score Change | Year  |
+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-------+
| A       |           -5 |                     5 | 13-14 |
| B       |            3 |                     3 | 13-14 |
| C       |           -8 |                     8 | 13-14 |
| D       |           -7 |                     7 | 13-14 |
| E       |           -1 |                     1 | 13-14 |
| A       |           -4 |                     4 | 14-15 |
| B       |            1 |                     1 | 14-15 |
| C       |           -4 |                     4 | 14-15 |   
| D       |           -4 |                     4 | 14-15 |
| E       |           -5 |                     5 | 14-15 |
| A       |           -5 |                     5 | 15-16 |
| B       |           -5 |                     5 | 15-16 |
| C       |            3 |                     3 | 15-16 |
| D       |           -4 |                     4 | 15-16 |
| E       |           -3 |                     3 | 15-16 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------------+-------+
```

Given this, I want to calculate what would consist of a significant change in score for any given student, compared to the average change in score for students. For example, if a student's score changed by more than 5 (x) points, this would be considered significant.

How can I calculate this "x"? Would it be as simple as finding the T-value associated with the score change at 95% CI (assuming this is what I'm interested in), and converting it back to a change in score?

In the same way, would the way to go be to look at score change or absolute score change? I'm not sure I understand what the difference in results would mean between the two.

If decided to go with the raw score change, would there be 2 numbers?: 
Significant if more than x points, or less than -y points.

Comment: This really looks like repeated measurements, and maybe it would be better to present it as such, and not only with the calculated change scores. Also, what is the goal? Are the scores averages, or a simple subject? ...